# string[length()] in C++, is it OK?

Tags: c++, string, c++11

My colleague's code looked like this:

```
void copy(std::string const& s, char *d) {
  for(int i = 0; i <= s.size(); i++, d++)
    *d = s[i];
}
```

His application crashes and I think that it is because this accesses `s` out of range, since the condition should go only up to `s.size() - 1`.

But other guys next to me says there was a discussion in the past about this being legal. Can anyone please clear this up for me?

Comment: I'd be more concerned about the destination pointer. Why doesn't that function take a size parameter?

Comment: Perhaps you should try to copy `s.c_str()` if you want to have the null terminator in the copy...

Comment: Oh, just a question. Are you sure you're really using C++11? Although support is increasing, many compilers still only implement a subset of it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's put aside the possiblity that `*d` is invalid since that has nothing to do with what the question seems directed at: whether or not `std::string operator[]()` has well defined behavior when accessing the "element" at index `std::string::size()`.

The C++03 standard has the following description of `string::operator[]()` (21.3.4 "`basic_string` element access"):

> ```
> const_reference operator[](size_type pos) const;
> reference operator[](size_type pos);
> ```
>
> Returns: If `pos < size()`, returns `data()[pos]`. Otherwise, if `pos
>   == size()`, the const version returns `charT()`.  Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Since `s` in the example code is `const`, the behavior is well defined and `s[s.size()]` will return a null character.  However, if `s` was not a `const string`, the behavior would be undefined.

C++11 remedies this odd-ball behavior of the `const` version behaving so differently than the non-const version in this edge case.  C++11 21.4.5 "`basic_string` element access" says:

> ```
> const_reference operator[](size_type pos) const;
> reference operator[](size_type pos);
> ```
>
> Requires: `pos <= size()`.
>
> Returns: `*(begin() + pos`) if `pos < size()`, otherwise a reference
>   to an object of type T with value `charT()`; the referenced value
>   shall not be modified.

So for a C++11 compiler, the behavior is well-defined whether or not the `string` is `const`.

Unrelated to the question, I find it a little strange that C++11 says that "the referenced value shall not be modified" - it's not clear to me if that clause applies only in the case where `pos == size()`.  I'm pretty sure there's a ton of existing code that does things like `s[i] = some_character;` where `s` is a non-const `std:string` and `i < s.size()`.  Is that undefined behavior now? I suspect that that clause applies only to the special-case `charT()` object.

Another interesting thing is that neither standard seems to require that the address of the object returned for `s[s.size()]` be in any way related to the address of the object returned for `s[s.size() - 1]`.  In other words, it seems like the returned `charT()` reference doesn't have to be contiguous to the end of the string data.  I suspect that this is to give implementers a choice to just return a reference to a single static copy of that sentinel element if desired (that would also explain C++11's "shall not be modified" restriction, assuming it applies only to the special case).

Comment: I find it amusing that `at`, however, does not allow being called with `size()` as an index.

Answer (score 8):

[cppreference says this:](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at)

> ```
> reference       operator[]( size_type pos );
>
> const_reference operator[]( size_type pos ) const;
> ```
>
> If `pos==size()`,
>
> - The const version returns a reference to the character with value CharT() (the null character). (until C++11)
> - Both versions returns a reference to the character with value CharT() (the null character). Modifying the null character through non-const reference results in undefined behavior. (since C++11)

So it is OK so long as you don't modify the null character.

Comment: The OP's code doesn't try to modify the std::string, it tries to read from the string and put it into the char array.

Comment: Just to be clear - if using a pre-C++11 compiler the access to `s[s.size()]` is undefined if `s` is not `const` - that access in the question's code is OK only because `s` is `const` (for a pre-C++11 compiler).  It has nothing to do with whether or not the null character is modified, only whether or not `s` is `const`.  Of course, none of this says anything about the possibility that `*d` may be invalid.

Comment: I find it amusing to cite a website to prove Standard conformance, lemme dig a bit ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it like that (your collegue's code tries to copy the terminating `\0` as well) you can

- use `c_str()`.
- use the loop with `i < s.size()` and append the `\0` manually afterwards.

Edit:
Well, judging by the other answers, I'm more inclined to think now that Abyx's comment is correct: the array `d` may be overflowing (or it may not even be assigned). Check that first.
But do make sure that you copy a `\0` too!