# Index not giving out of bonds error in Roman to integer

Tags: c++

I  was looking at the solution for roman to integer but I am not sure why this is not getting index out of bound error

```
class Solution {
public:
    int romanToInt(string s) {
        unordered_map<char, int> m;
        
        m['I'] = 1;
        m['V'] = 5;
        m['X'] = 10;
        m['L'] = 50;
        m['C'] = 100;
        m['D'] = 500;
        m['M'] = 1000;
        
        int ans = 0;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){

            // std::cout << m[s[i+1]] << std::endl; 
            // std::cout << s.length() << std::endl;
            std::cout << i+1 << std::endl;

            std::cout << s[i] << " and " << s[i+1] << std::endl;

            if(m[s[i]] < m[s[i+1]]){
                ans -= m[s[i]];
            }
            else{
                ans += m[s[i]];
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
};
```

Comment: Where do you expect an index out of bounds error, and *why* do you expect it? Have you read the documentation of the class you're using, or are you just assuming it works the same way as a similar class in a language you already know (e.g. Java's HashMap or C#'s Dictionary)?

Comment: Note that if you go out of bound of the `std::string` then you'll have **undefined behavior** which means anything can happen including but not limited to the program giving your expected output. But never rely on the output of a program that has UB. The program may just crash.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Probably in the `s[i+1]` part. But OP should clarify that in their question.

Comment: Don't assume that all languages work like languages you're already familiar with, and that you don't need to learn their fundamental principles first.

Comment: `s[i]` doesn't check the index, `s.at(i)` does. See [string::at](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at)

Comment: For debugging (and only for debugging) compile with `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` (gcc, clang and some other compilers) or just run the debug build (Microsoft compiler), then the `[]` operators from the standard C++ library will do bounds checking and crash with an error message if an out of bounds access is done.

Comment: It is totally fine to access `str[str.size()]` in a string `str`. There is no out of bounds in your code. The duplicate is relevant but doest not contain the answer. Read here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at

Comment: @user12002570 `s[i+1]` is not out of bounds, there is no undefined behavior in the code.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Yes, for `std::string` it is well-defined but for c-style arrays it is undefined. Though OP should clarify where they expect out of bound error.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I think OP is expecting `s[i+i]` to give error but it won't because from c++11 it is well-defined. I'll add another dupe that explains why we can access the last char of a std::string. [`string[length()]` in C++, is it OK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570534/stringlength-in-c-is-it-ok)

Comment: Does your code handle these numbers correctly: IV, VI, IX, XI, XL, CM?